# Git pull from master branch being in other branch

Tags: git, git-checkout

I created a new branch from the `master` and changed few files. How can i pull fresh files from `master` being in newly created branch and ignore/overwrite changed files in current branch?

Comment: When you say "_pull_", do you mean pulling changes from a remote repository (`origin/master`) or just restoring the files in your new branch to match your local `master` branch?

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio I want to restore the files in new branch to match `master` branch

Comment: Why dont you delete the branch locally and create a new branch with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You can undo your local changes and restore the files as they're in the `master` branch by saying:

```sh
git checkout master -- .
```

where the `--` tells Git to interpret whatever comes next as a list of paths and the `.` indicates all paths.

---

If you're using [Git 2.23 (August 2019)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.23.0.txt) or later, you can use the new (but still *experimental*) [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) command:

```sh
git restore master -- .
```

From the [release notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.23.0.txt#L61-L65):

> Two new commands "git switch" and "git restore" are introduced to split "checking out a branch to work on advancing its history" and "checking out paths out of the index and/or a tree-ish to work on advancing the current history" out of the single "git checkout"

Essentially, the two things that `git checkout` does have now received dedicated commands:

- `git switch` to check out a branch and update the working directory accordingly
- `git restore` to check out files from a specific commit (or the index) in the working directory

Answer (score 0):

There are a lots of ways to do it. Some are shown below.

- If you want your current branch to be exactly same as your local `master` branch, you should just run the following command. This will remove all your changes.

  ```sh
  $ git reset --hard master
  ```
- If you want your current branch to be exactly same as your remote `master` branch, you should just run the following commands. We should fetch the remote branches just to be sure that they are all synced.

  ```sh
  $ git fetch origin
  $ git reset --hard origin/master
  ```
- Another way is to delete the current branch and create a new branch from `master` with the same name. Before doing so, if you have some uncommitted data, you should stash them or make a commit.

  - To stash the uncommitted data, run the following command.

    ```sh
    $ git add .; git stash; git stash drop
    ```
  - **Or** to commit the changes, run the following command.

    ```sh
    $ git add .; git commit -m "just commit & it won't be after a while"
    ```

  And finally delete and create the branch by running the following command.

  ```sh
  $ git checkout master
  $ git branch -D <branch-name>
  $ git branch <branch-name>
  ```